# Why is method 1 called instead of method 2?

Tags: c++, overloading

I am confused why method 1 is called instead of method 2 for the following code segment? The number of parameters in method 2 is an exact match with the call so why method2 is not called?

```
bool addOraclePolygonFeatures(long l, int  i=2)
{
  //method 1

  cout<<"method1\n";
  return true;
}

// Function 2
bool addOraclePolygonFeatures(int i)
{
  //method 2

  cout<<"method2\n";
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  long l=4;
  int  i=3;
  addOraclePolygonFeatures(l);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1 is called because it is an exact match; method 2 requires a downcast.

Answer (score 2):

**l** has a type **long** that is why *function 1* is called. And the other parameters will have default value to match with the *function 1*.
And *function 2* has parameter type *int* for which the calling function's parameter(*viz of type long here*) will have to *downcast* and in that process some data may loss.

Answer (score 1):

Because method 2 is best match for provided argument (long), the second argument is default argument means i will have value of 2 when you call

```
addOraclePolygonFeatures(long l, int  i=2)
```

function with one argument. Incase you call  addOraclePolygonFeatures with two arguments, the value of i will be over-written.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a function with a single `long`.  You have two candidates: one that takes an `int`, and one that takes a `long` and an optional `int`.  The one taking a single `int` is not the best match because it may lose data if the number passed in is too large to fit in an `int`.